# Creating a Navigation bar on a map activity Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have this map activity and i want to make a navigation bar/ drawer in it.
there's an error in MapsActivity says "cannot resolve method setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)"

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   
 OnMapReadyCallback {

String [] places= {"bais city","basay","bindoy"};
AutoCompleteTextView textview;

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LatLng latLng;
private Marker marker;

private Toolbar category;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready  
      to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
      getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    category = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Navbar);
    setSupportActionBar(category); //i got my error here says cannot resolve  
     method

}
```

Imports

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Maps activity layout (xml)

```
<!--suppress ALL -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PSString"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="278dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BTNSearch"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:onClick="onSearch" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="384dp"
        android:layout_height="554dp"
        tools:context="com.example.boneyflesh.homepage.MapsActivity"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Navbar layout (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/Navbar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void whatodo(View view){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.BTNStart){
        AlertDialog.Builder prompt = new  
        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        prompt.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Documents", new 
                  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
                            which) {

                            }
                        }
                )
                    .setNegativeButton("2D MAP", new 
                     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int 
                         which) {
                            startActivity(new 
                        Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));
                        }
                    }
                    );


        AlertDialog alert = prompt.create();
        alert.setTitle("Please select an option");
        alert.show();

    }
    if(view.getId() == R.id.BTNInfo){

    }
    if(view.getId() == R.id.BTNClose){
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't resolve the `setSupportActionBar()` method because that method is not implemented in `FragmentActivity`.  Ideally you should be inheriting your activity from `AppCompatActivity`, which will allow you to work with the toolbar, as well as with fragments.

Comment: ive edited my post,, im really new to this stuff,how do i do that with my setup on MainActivity?
ive set my on Alert dialog to open the maps activity.

Comment: ...instead of `extends FragmentActivity`, it should be `extends AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: thanks,, errors gone but im still struggling on how to draw out the navigation bar,, ill be tinkering a bit. :thumbs-up: